# Parallax CSS Scroll with "Layers"

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, scroll, parallax

I need to have a 'layered look' in a part of my homepage. Something like this below

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html

Especially from Slide 3 to Slide 4 the way it shows the items starting from the bottom and then upwards

I tried this

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: blue;
}

#revealed-section {
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

#revealed-section-placeholder {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">Scroll down!</div>
<div id="revealed-section-placeholder"></div>
<div id="revealed-section">
    <h1> Content here </h1> <br/><br/>
    <h1> Content here </h1> <br/><br/>
    <h1> Content here </h1> <br/><br/>
    <h1> Content here </h1> <br/><br/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qYbs7/1/

But my problem is that this works if its a complete Page solution, but once I want it as a component in my React page it doesn't work. The bottom: 0 for example goes to the very bottom of my homepage and its not containered in a div.

Maybe I'm overlooking something but it would be so much help if someone more experienced could make that code into a copy and paste react component ideally with tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `position: fixed`, because when you use a fixed position, the element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

[This website](https://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html) uses an attribute called `background-attachment`. The `background-attachment` property sets whether a background image scrolls with the rest of the page or is fixed. On [This website](https://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html), especially from slide 3 to slide 4, it's  better to say, it creates a fixed background image that appears slowly on scroll. You can read more about parallax scrolling in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp). But you should know the `background-attachment` property is the key for creating parallax scrolling. Try this:

```html
    <div id="main">Scroll down!</div>
    <div id="revealed-section">
        <h1> Content here </h1> <br /><br />
        <h1> Content here </h1> <br /><br />
        <h1> Content here </h1> <br /><br />
        <h1> Content here </h1> <br /><br />
    </div>
```

and this is css part:

```css
#main {
    background-image: url("https://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/images/Slide4/desktop4.jpg");
    min-height: 700px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

#revealed-section {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

The output is this, similar to [your example](https://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html) and [w3school example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax_percent)

[image]

Comment: Hey Mohamdi first of all thank you for your response I really appreciate it

But when I try the code I dont get the effect of the upper div slowly revealing the elements in the div below. Maybe my example was bad, I'm looking for something like the 1 and 2 example here:

https://www.wix.com/blog/what-is-parallax-scrolling-explained-with-examples

The way its slowly pulling the div above like a "curtain" and revealing the content

Comment: @Mlk I updated my answer, but you can change the HTML elements and use the Image for second element if you want.